# How to show rows by date from now?

Tags: mysql, database

I need a way to show the rows ordered by date ( ascending ) but with the date from now. I am using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM status 
ORDER BY YEAR(datestart), MONTH(datestart), DAY(datestart) ASC
```

but it still shows the rows older than today.

This is the database structure:

```
id, status, datestart
```

database:

```
0,blabla,2015-02-12 16:15:12
1,blabla,2017-02-12 16:15:12
2,blabla,2016-08-11 19:13:22
4,blabla,2016-01-27 11:12:02
5,blabla,2016-07-21 18:12:02
6,blabla,2018-03-22 13:35:22
8,blabla,2016-08-15 17:12:32
```

expected results:

```
5,blabla,2016-07-21 18:12:02
2,blabla,2016-08-11 19:13:22
8,blabla,2016-08-15 17:12:32
1,blabla,2017-02-12 16:15:12
5,blabla,2018-03-22 13:35:22
```

Comment: can you show us the table structure, some data example and expected result?

Comment: add a `WHERE` clause to filter out older records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM status  WHERE datestart > now()
ORDER BY YEAR(datestart), MONTH(datestart), DAY(datestart) ASC
```

Comment: Can I use mysql function in production environment ?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use it. But be carefull to the environment timezone.